# Performance issue with Django and Postgres on a single update

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have an intermittent performance issue with Django and Postgres when updating a single line in a small "< 1m" rows table.

The APM reports the issue on the update line, which is:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=model_id).update(field=True)
```

The filter clause uses the primary key of the table and the query executed by django is:

```
'UPDATE "model" SET "field" = true WHERE "model"."id" = 12345'
```

The error is raised because the execution takes more than 5s.

This code runs in a celery task which receives the id of the model as the argument and executes normally most of the time.

I know it's a very open question but any idea or help on what might be happening is appreciated.

I'm running out Python 3.7, Django 2.0.13, and Postgres 9.5.

Comment: Are the columns involved in the filter indexed?  If you run the [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) directly on Postgres with an `EXPLAIN ` before it, what does it return?

Comment: I did update the question with this information. Thanks.

Comment: The question update got lost somewhere probably, because I cant see there the information about the column's index nor `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: You can enable [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/auto-explain.html) to automatically log the `EXPLAIN` for slow queries (there may be a performance hit if you have a lot of slow queries).

Comment: It is likely blocked on a lock.  You can set log_lock_waits to make it log lock waits that are longer than deadlock_timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because we were triggering the task, but sometimes it was being executed before the current transaction was committed, ending up in a lock.

The solution was to use django on_commit hook as follows:

```
class DoSomethingTask(Task):
    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        transaction.on_commit(
            lambda: super(DoSomethingTask, self).apply_async(*args, **kwargs))


@app.task(base=DoSomethingTask,...)
def do_something(tutor_id):
    ...
```